# some syntax puzzles in C + + about Bit field

Tags: c++, bit-fields

I've had some problems about the following code。

```
int a;
const int b = 0;
struct S {
    // simple cases
    int x1 : 8 = 42;                 // OK; "= 42" is brace-or-equal-initializer
    int x2 : 8 { 42 };               // OK; "{ 42 }" is brace-or-equal-initializer
    // ambiguities
    int y1 : true ? 8 : a = 42;      // OK; brace-or-equal-initializer is absent
    int y2 : true ? 8 : b = 42;      // error: cannot assign to const int
    int y3 : (true ? 8 : b) = 42;    // OK; "= 42" is brace-or-equal-initializer
    int z : 1 || new int { 0 };      // OK; brace-or-equal-initializer is absent
};
```

the link [Bit field-cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field)

I found the code in cppreference when i study Bit field。i cant understand how it works。Actually, I don't quite understand y1，y2,y3 and z.
why the value of y1 is -52？ What is the running order of this line of code？
Hope to get your help, thank you

Comment: Please add the link to cppreference.

Comment: Tip: In practice bitfields don't really work, they're highly non-portable, and they're generally not worth the trouble.

Comment: The value of `y1` is indeterminate because it does not have an initializer. (as the comment says, "brace-or-equal-initializer is absent.") Just stay away from the ambiguous cases, they are not useful.

Comment: what different between y1 and y3

Comment: In y1 42 is part of the expression for size, in y3 42 is an initializer. All these ambiguous cases are only interesting for compiler writers. In practice, if you ever use bitfields, their sizes are just numbers.

Comment: `y1` is parsed as `int y1 : (true ? 8 : (a = 42))`.  That is, `y1` is an uninitialized bitfield with a width of 42 bits and the side-effect of assigning a value of `42` to `a`.

Comment: thank you，i got it。`a = 42` is not running.